# In Java, how do I stream characters directly to an Oracle clob/xmltype column without storing the values in memory?

Tags: oracle, clob, xmltype

I wrote code that used a SQLXML object to get a Writer and then save that object to the DB. However, I just found out that the SQLXML Writer is nothing but a wrapper around a ByteArrayOutputStream. That means that if I write 3GB of data to the writer then that'll take 3GB of heap. That's not what I want.

Is there really no way to write to a clob/xmltype column in Oracle without storing it locally first?

If there really isn't a way to do this I'll just create a new table that stores a subset of the data for each entry. Perhaps I could then combine the results in the DB somehow, but this really seems like a hack to me. I just want to open a stream, write to it, then close it.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming is supported in jdbc or in hibernate.
In JDBC you can use like below

```
InputStream data = resultset.getBinaryStream(1)
```